# R mac catalina tabulizer fails with java runtime missing error but java is installed

Tags: r, rjava, tabulizer

I'd like to use tabulizer to extract tables from a pdf. It installs fine and the library(tabulizer) loads fine. But when I attempt to run extract_tables from a pdf on my laptop, I'm told `No Java runtime present, requesting install.` I'm on a mac with Catalina. Java is installed and I have run `R CMD javareconf` but that doesn't help. Some responses to earlier versions of this problem point to this website - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US but the older version of Java there can't be installed.